# Is there a dataset for products (UPC/EAN level) and their recycling information?

Tags: dataset

I am looking to do some analysis around plastic recycling and interested to know if there is any dataset that gives recycling information for products sold in US. For ex: a product with UPC/EAN number has a resin code of 1 (number written at the bottom of a plastic container). If you have any ideas on how to start creating it will be helpful as well. I understand there is something out there that gives information of a general 1 gallon milk container but I am looking at information on a brand/manufacturer level.

Thanks

Comment: My understanding of your post is that you want a recommendation for a database or dataset that would be indexed by UPC/EAN bar codes and would contain a field that would indicate the container material (plastic, glass, aluminum, etc.) along with additional information about the container material such as the plastic resin code or the glass color. The information you are actually interested in is a subset of that data for plastic containers only. You want to be able to scan a bar code from a container and then use the dataset to retrieve the container's plastic resin code?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks Richard. Do you have any ideas if there is something out there or what can be a good place to start?

Comment: Seems doubtful. I'm not sure as to the probability of changing container resins nor am I sure if the same bar code is used with similar sized products but different containers. It doesn't appear to be something that a manufacturer would be interested in tracking without some kind of regulatory requirements which implies that someone other than the manufacturer would be responsible for such a list that would be subject to all the vagaries of keeping it up to date when you don't own the bar codes or products.

Comment: @NishantBansal were you able to find such a dataset?